# How to hide text printed from DB

Tags: php, text, show-hide

I have now some question about hiding some characters ... I want to hide first few characters fro user name on account management. Here is my problem:
On account management I have $username in table which is taken from DB an I need this username not to be displayed like this:
Username => ***rname - just replace few first characters with "*" using php or similar code for webpages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't want to let them know how many characters are in the username, either? Use [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
$val = 'username';
$output = substr_replace($val, '**', 0, -5);
```

Outputs: `**rname`

Of course if a username is shorter this won't work. You could instead do

```
$output = substr_replace($val, '**', 0, 3); // or some other length value
```

Comment: Yes, the third parameter is the start of the replacement, the fourth is the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '***' . substr($username, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to say. Do you want to achieve this?

```
echo '***', substr($username, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this

```
<?php
$username = theusernamehere;
$userhide = str_pad(substr($username, -4), strlen($username), 'x', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$userhide = str_replace('xxxx','xx',$userhide);
echo $userhide;

?>
```

Comment: it is an answer for your question. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do;

```
print '***'.substr($username, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($username, 2);
```

remove first two chars from the string.